# Framework7 google maps not loading on second page click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, html-framework-7

Hi I have a problem using framework7 at first load the map is loading when I navigate to a different page then click back to the  page with the google map the map doesn't load.

```
if (page.name === 'location') {
         new GMaps({
          div: '#map',
          lat: -12.043333,
          lng: -77.028333
        });

}
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Hi mat this is my fidle https://jsfiddle.net/yxc1q9ny/

Comment: my problem is when I hit refresh the map appear while if I navigate and go to other page navigation then go back to the page with the map the map wont load anymore. it only load at the first time

Comment: I get this error "ReferenceError: Framework7 is not defined" with your fiddle

Comment: Please help sire badly needed for my program Im using framework7.io building a native android app.

Comment: I cant post the whole html in fiddle cause its has an html template and the pages is created via dynamic views.

Comment: You are missing External Resources references for your js and css files, add them to the fiddle please

Answer (score 2):

For Those using framework 7 and encounter this error Id like to post what I did to make it right just investigated that the elements in framework7's pages are cached when navigating to each pages thats why google maps can only appear on first navigation of the page with map the second time you navigate the page is duplicated from which the DOM your targeting is on the cache thats why its not appearing in the second time you navigate to the page with googlemap.

```
 var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
   domCache:false,
 });
```

set the domcache to false; By default its true. You need to make it false to load your map properly.