# Framework7 external APIs don't work when you return to relevant subpage (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

I have encountered this problem with Framework7 for a couple of times. First time with cordova-plugin-ibeacon, then with phonegap-launch-navigator, gmaps.js and now even with built-in [animated tabs](http://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html#animated-tabs).

I will describe the problem with gmaps.js as an example.
On the index.html I insert div with google maps using gmap.js API. It works fine. When I navigate to another page and return to index.html google maps no longer works. It's just grey, inactive, nothing is visible in the div. No error outputs to console or anything.

Exact same behaviour with all the APIs mentioned above + framework7's animated tabs that just get inactive after returning to page.

Since this happens to every external API I have already worked with, I assume this is some Framework7 related issue.

Maybe something connected with routing? I use [Ajax Pages](http://framework7.io/docs/pages-ajax.html) for navigation. Maybe deviceready event should be involved somehow?

Other issue that might be connected with this one is that those APIs work only on the index.html. If I use them on any subpage, it just doesn't work, no error outputs to console. It just has to be on home page.

I have create git repository specifically to indicate my issue here https://github.com/wiewioraseb/framework7-basic-app
It's ready to use repository (no additional configuration needed), just open it in PhoneGap as indicated in README.md and change pages with buttons on the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Please provide JSFiddle Link  .Thanks

Comment: @HassanALi: I have added git repository with my issue. Just navigate to another page and go back. You will notice google maps turning grey. Don't bother with errors in console.log(). They are connected with google statistics.

Comment: Well it turned out the default "domCache:true" was the cause. I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40542519/framework7-google-maps-not-loading-on-second-page-click?rq=1 . My question is a duplicate.